# About Cardinal Exponentiation

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I know the definition of a cardinal to the power of another cardinal:

> $|A|^{|B|}=|$the set of all functions from $B$ to $A|$

I also know that $2^{|A|}=|\mathscr{P}(A)|$.
My question is:

> Is there a more generalized, simple answer for any integer to the power of a cardinal? Like $3^{|A|}?$

Comment: For an integer $n\ge 2$ and infinite set $A$ we have $n^{|A|}=2^{|A|}=|\wp(A)|$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank You

Comment: Your welcome.$\,$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BrianM.Scott commented, for an integer $n\ge2$ and an infinite set $A$, $n^{|A|}=2^{|A|}=|\mathscr{P}(A)|$.